# ADF - Cosmos DB Linked service unauthorized due to client IP not whitelisted

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to create a source dataset in ADF and while reusing a linked service that used work to access cosmos DB or SQL Database I am getting the following error when I try to test the connection. Existing activities are running fine without any issue but only when I try to reuse the linked service or create a new linked service I am getting this erro

[image]

As I understand it could not be an issue in Data factory(as existing jobs are running fine) what can be the issue in my system or setup that is causing the issue? I tried connecting and disconnecting my VPN but still it isn't working

Comment: Please edit to provide more detail. Also, this doesn't seem to be related to either Cosmos DB or SQL Database (you mention that the issue happens with linked service instances to both database instances). This seems like something specific to your ADF instance and related linked services.

Comment: could you please provide image of your linked service?

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar error when though the ADF client IP was whitelisted in cosmos db firewall rules the  `Allow access from Azure portal` option was not ticked.
To ensure that you have the required connection to the resource, confirm that you have the ADF IP address added to the client IP list in firewall settings of networking section of cosmos db. Also
ensure that the  `Allow access from Azure portal` is ticked. Below is the screenshot which shows the same:

[image]

After updating of firewall rule, I tested the connection of linked service it tested successfully.

[image]